# ##[error]No agent found in pool TestPool which satisfies the following demand (Using intel Mac)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I was trying to use a self-hosted agent to create my pipeline on azure.
But I got this error

> ##[error]No agent found in pool TestPool which satisfies the following demand: VisualStudio. All demands: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1

the agent is running without error
[image]

and pipeline settings YAML file:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: TestPool
  vmImage: 'macOS-12'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '_buildOutput/**'
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

I have done the exact same thing on a windows machine, and it works fine, does anyone got any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Use cross-platform commands like `dotnet build` and `dotnet test`. As the error message indicates, `VSBuild` and `VsTest` are only for Windows machines, since there isn't a true port of Visual Studio to MacOS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Didn't notice that. I'm totally new to c# world.